# Turn off 2sxc Content Item Title as Module Title

Tags: dotnetnuke-7, 2sxc

Is there a way of turning of the 2sxc feature that replaces the module title with the Content Item Title (in the case of a list, it seems to use the Title of the first Content Item in the list)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set the ListContent title.

If you have a list, then you must have two Content Types set: 1 for the Content item, and 1 for the ListContent. If you have a Title in the ListContent, that will set the module title.